# Blitting to the screen, NodeJS and OpenVG

Tags: python, video, streaming-video

I have managed to get 4 rtsp video streams from IP cameras to render on my screen via multiple instances of omxplayer. However, I would like to add some text and graphics to this screen with information such as weather and sensor data.

What is the best way to do this? Is it all possible within python? Is pygame suitable for this? How do I combine omxplayer and pygame? Or should I rather do everything within python?

Any there any other technologies that allows hw accelerated blitting to the Pi via HDMI?

Comment: Would JavaFX be a valid alternative?

Comment: Do you want to put data on top of the video, or do you leave room around the videos for this? Are you using X, or do you run everything from the console? Since the video's are hardware accelerated, they rendered on a 'layer' above things like the console. I'm currently experimenting with open-vg, which to is hardware accelerated.

Comment: yes, i am reserving space around the video for the additional information. Because of the video running in 'overlay' mode.

yes, i am running from the console

Comment: open-vg looks really interesting. also the fact that you can run an HTML5 canvas on top. node-js support is also a real plus. however, still need accelerated rtsp streaming h264 playback. do you suggested i stick with omxplayer and build the rest around it?

Comment: I don't know a lot about rtsp, and I don't know any alternative to omxplayer. Loading the video stream in Node and displaying it would most likely not work (bad performance and a lot of work). So just stick with omxplayer, and have openvg layer for the other info. You'd have to check if openvg is rendered above or below the video layers. PS I was hesitant to mention I was using Node, but it seems you like it. Please note that node-openvg-canvas doesn't run on version 0.10. I compiled 0.8.23 myself. It takes a few hours to compile though :-)

Comment: seems openvg renders on top of the video. omxplayer uses openvg to render subtitles.

Comment: Cool. Nice to know. I might want to add video to my project in the future, so just running omx in the background and clearing the canvas should show the video. Thanks for sharing.